# mysql how to return 0 if category is not sold in specific month

Tags: mysql

im trying to return a list of categories sold by month.
My query:
`select count(*) counter, monthname(sales.date) month_name, sales.date, models.name, models.code, models.price, models.size, models.quantity, models.image, models.image_type, models.image_name, categories.name, categories.color from sales inner join models on models.code = sales.code inner JOIN categories on models.category_id = categories.id where year(sales.date) = year(curdate()) GROUP by month(sales.date), categories.name`

My result:
[image]

This work well but as you can see for month "January" category "Sandaletti" is missing.. but i want to return 0 in counter when this appear like counter 0 month_name January name SANDALETTI

I don't know how i can do.. anyone can help please?

Comment: Removed the DBMS tags. Please tag the question with the DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: You need to select **from** your categories table and **outer join** to the result of the other aggregations

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, starting by selecting all your categories and then applying the aggregated totals for each.

*Edited after you tagged as mysql*

```
select x.*, c.name, c.color  /* You may need to specify individual columns in order to use isnull() for where there are no category results */
from categories c
left join (
    select Count(*) counter, monthname(s.date) month_name, s.date, 
    m.name, m.code, m.price, m.size, m.quantity, m.image, 
    m.image_type, m.image_name, m.category_id
    from sales s inner join models m on s.code = m.code
    where Year(s.date) = Year(curdate())
    group by Month(s.date), m.category_id
)x on x.category_id=c.id
```

Comment: Hello sTTU, thanks for your help and sorry for sql tag.. i tried this query but is the same resuls as my initial query

Comment: Im trying to release this with a new table 'months'  with id month and name.. i tried this : SELECT count(c.name) as counter, monthname(b.date), c.name FROM ( select id from months ) a LEFT JOIN sales b ON a.id = month(b.date) AND year(b.date) = year(curdate()) AND month(b.date) IN (a.id) LEFT JOIN models m on b.code = m.code LEFT JOIN categories c on m.category_id = c.id GROUP BY month(b.date), c.name now i have the same result but with new row with counter 0 but the name of category and month name is NULL.. did you know how i can do please ?